# How to create a PHP page that loads dynamic/different content depending on which link is clicked?

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML page with a list of  links. Each link will link to the same PHP page. I want the PHP page to dynamically load a different  link depending on which link id is clicked on the previous HTML page.

HTML Page ↓

```
<a id="link1" href="test.php">Download</a>
<a id="link2" href="test.php">Download</a>
<a id="link3" href="test.php">Download</a>
...
```

PHP page will print out a specific link depending on which a id was clicked on the previous HTML page ↓

```
<a id="link1" href="thisisaspecificlink.com">Link here</a>
```

I'm a total noob at PHP and would greatly appreciate assistance of any kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve these but at the most basic level you can pass a GET variable and use that as your link:

e.g.

```
<a id="link1" href="test.php?link=download.com">Download</a>
<a id="link2" href="test.php?link=download2.com">Download</a>
<a id="link3" href="test.php?link=download3.com">Download</a>

<a href="http://<?=$_GET['link'];?>">Link here</a>
```

In this example you are passing **link** as a `$_GET` variable and then using it in the `<a>` tag on the 2nd page

Another way is to, again pass a $_GET variable but then use an IF statement on the 2nd page e.g.

```
<a id="link1" href="test.php?link=1">Download</a>
<a id="link2" href="test.php?link=2">Download</a>
<a id="link3" href="test.php?link=3">Download</a>


$link = $_GET['link'];
if($link == 1) { $linkURL = "http://www.download.com";}
if($link == 2) { $linkURL = "http://www.download2.com";}
if($link == 3) { $linkURL = "http://www.download3.com";}

<a href="<?=$linkURL;?>">Link here</a>
```

The above example is a little bit longer but wanted to include so you can see different ways of achieving what you're looking for. And give you a better idea of how to pass and handle variables from page to page.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I go about only showing *one* of the links on the PHP page, depending on which link is clicked on the HTML page?

Your example code shows id "link1" – how would I show only link2 if link2 is clicked instead?

Comment: The id in the PHP page is irrelevant (I have removed it from my answer for clarity). It is not linked to the HTML in any way. It is the $link (first example) or $linkURL (2nd example) that determines the link URL shown. The examples above show one link depending on which one is clicked on the HTML page.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense now. I will mark your answer as correct and give it a shot! Thanks.

Comment: Check out my latest PHP question. It relates to this one. I haven't been able to figure it out! Thanks :)

Comment: I provided an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way:
Here suppose you want redirect page to about-us.php page you can directly put in

```
<a href="about-us.php">
```

or try this

This is your html page

```
<a id="link1" href="test.php?link=aboutuspage">link</a>
```

On test.php page need to get this link 
    now check link is equal to about-us page or another page

```
if($_GET['link']=="aboutuspage"){
 //redirect to aboutus page
 header("Location:about-us.php");
}
```

Note: This is untested code